# Can i add a calculated value in VBA to a hover mouseover for a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if it possible for VBA to calculate something and then put this information so that when I hover over a cell, I see that information. The cell itself will actually hold a different value...

For example:

```
.Cells.Value = Round((ds.Cells(x, 57).Value _
                / ds.Cells(x, 40).Value) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                & ds.Cells(x, 57).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 40).Value & ")"

.Cells(ltaLR + 1, "K").Value = Round((ds.Cells(x, 71).Value _
                / ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                & ds.Cells(x, 71).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 41).Value & ")"
```

Can I split this code into two so that

```
& ds.Cells(x, 71).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 41).Value
```

gets added to the mouse hover?

I am looking to incorporate it in to this code:

```
Sub LTATradesTest()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim LastRow As Long, fs As Worksheet, ds As Worksheet, x As Long
Dim ltaLR As Long

With ThisWorkbook
    Set fs = .Worksheets("Filters")
    Set ds = .Worksheets("Data")
End With

LastRow = ds.Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

ClearSelections
SortData
DeleteCF

For x = 4 To LastRow

    If ds.Cells(x, 1) = ds.Range("E1") And ds.Cells(x, 40) >= _
        fs.Range("C2") And ds.Cells(x, 41) >= fs.Range("C2") Then

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LTA")

            ltaLR = .Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1

            .Cells(ltaLR, "B").Value = ds.Cells(x, 3)
            .Cells(ltaLR, "B").Resize(2, 1).Merge
            .Cells(ltaLR, "C").Value = ds.Cells(x, 4)
            .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "C").Value = ds.Cells(x, 5)
            .Cells(ltaLR, "D").Value = ds.Cells(x, 81)
            .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "D").Value = ds.Cells(x, 91)
            .Cells(ltaLR, "E").Value = ds.Cells(x, 82)
            .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "E").Value = ds.Cells(x, 92)
            .Cells(ltaLR, "F").Value = ds.Cells(x, 83)
            .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "F").Value = ds.Cells(x, 93)
            .Cells(ltaLR, "G").Value = ds.Cells(x, 84)
            .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "G").Value = ds.Cells(x, 94)
            .Cells(ltaLR, "H").Value = ds.Cells(x, 85)
            .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "H").Value = ds.Cells(x, 96)
            .Cells(ltaLR, "I").Value = ds.Cells(x, 95)
            .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "I").Value = ds.Cells(x, 86)
            .Cells(ltaLR, "J").Value = ds.Cells(x, 88)
            .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "J").Value = ds.Cells(x, 98)

            .Cells(ltaLR, "K").Value = Round((ds.Cells(x, 57).Value _
                / ds.Cells(x, 40).Value) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                & ds.Cells(x, 57).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 40).Value & ")"
            .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "K").Value = Round((ds.Cells(x, 71).Value _
                / ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                & ds.Cells(x, 71).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 41).Value & ")"
            .Cells(ltaLR, "L").Value = Round((ds.Cells(x, 58).Value _
                / ds.Cells(x, 40).Value) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                & ds.Cells(x, 58).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 40).Value & ")"
            .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "L").Value = Round((ds.Cells(x, 72).Value _
                / ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                & ds.Cells(x, 72).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 41).Value & ")"

            .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 229).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 243).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                & (ds.Cells(x, 229).Value + ds.Cells(x, 243).Value) & "/" _
                & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
            .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "M").Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 257).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 275).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                & (ds.Cells(x, 257).Value + ds.Cells(x, 275).Value) & "/" _
                & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
            .Cells(ltaLR, "N").Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 54).Value + _
                ds.Cells(x, 68).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                & (ds.Cells(x, 54).Value + ds.Cells(x, 68).Value) & "/" _
                & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
            .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "N").Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 55).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 69).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                & (ds.Cells(x, 55).Value + ds.Cells(x, 69).Value) & "/" _
                & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
            .Cells(ltaLR, "O").Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 56).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 70).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                & (ds.Cells(x, 56).Value + ds.Cells(x, 70).Value) & "/" _
                & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
            .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "O").Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 59).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 73).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                & (ds.Cells(x, 59).Value + ds.Cells(x, 73).Value) & "/" _
                & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
            .Cells(ltaLR, "P").Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 144).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 159).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                & (ds.Cells(x, 144).Value + ds.Cells(x, 159).Value) & "/" _
                & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
            .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "P").Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 147).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 162).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                & (ds.Cells(x, 147).Value + ds.Cells(x, 162).Value) & "/" _
                & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"

        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.addcomment

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add code to an event - either when the sheet calculates, or when a specific cell changes.

This code will change the text in a comment that has been added to `Sheet1!D7`.
If the cell doesn't already contain a comment you'll get a run-time error 91 - *Object variable or With block variable not set*.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Dim ds As Worksheet
    Dim x As Long

    Set ds = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    x = 4

'    Reference the comment by name.
'    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Comment 2") _
'        .TextFrame.Characters.Text = ds.Cells(x, 71) & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 41)

'    Reference the comment in the cell range.
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D7").Comment.Text _
        Text:=ds.Cells(x, 71) & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 41)

'    Look at each comment on the sheet.
'    Numerics must be converted to text (Cstr).
'    Dim cmt As Comment
'    For Each cmt In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Comments
'        If cmt.Shape.Name = "Comment 1" Then
'            cmt.Text Text:=CStr(Rnd(5))
'        End If
'    Next cmt

End Sub
```

**Edit:**
To incorporate into your code you could use the code similar to below.  I've added two methods - one updates the comment if it exists, the other deletes it and reinserts it.
These comments will stay static unless you add code to change them when the calculations update.

```
Sub LTATradesTest()

    Dim ds As Worksheet
    Dim x As Long
    Dim ltaLR As Long
    Dim cmntText As String
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set ds = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    ltaLR = 3
    LastRow = 20

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LTA")
        For x = 4 To LastRow

            '.....
            '.Cells(ltaLR + 1, "J").Value = ds.Cells(x, 98)

            .Cells(ltaLR, "K").Value = Round((ds.Cells(x, 57).Value _
                            / ds.Cells(x, 40).Value) * 100, 0) & "%"

'            Adds or updates the comment text.
'            cmntText = ds.Cells(x, 57).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 40).Value
'            If Not HasComment(.Cells(ltaLR, "K")) Then
'                .Cells(ltaLR, "K").AddComment Text:=cmntText
'            Else
'                .Cells(ltaLR, "K").Comment.Text Text:=cmntText
'            End If

'           Deletes and reinserts the comment.
            If HasComment(.Cells(ltaLR, "K")) Then
                .Cells(ltaLR, "K").Comment.Delete
            End If
            .Cells(ltaLR, "K").AddComment Text:=ds.Cells(x, 57).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 40).Value

            '....

        Next x
    End With

End Sub

Public Function HasComment(Target As Range) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        With Target
            HasComment = Not .Comment Is Nothing
        End With
    Else
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 513, "HasComment()", "Argument must reference single cell."
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Module1.HasComment."
            Err.Clear
            Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Select

End Function
```

Your code looks like it's updating the same cells with different values of `x` though.

Comment: Thank you for you response. I have updated my OP. Here is my Code that i want to incorporate the mouseover in:

Comment: Thanks, yes, basically i have a different sheet (ds "data sheet") which has a varying amount of rows and 294 columns of data on. This sheet searches through that data and when various criteria are met it copies different values over to as many rows as needed...

Comment: Here is a link to the spreadsheet https://www.dropbox.com/s/mlwss7s3ueqx6o7/Filters.xlsm?dl=0